# Android Studio Device Manager Screenshot Failing

Tags: android, android-studio, screenshot, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to take a screenshot with from a AVD on Android Studio but every time I do I get error messages from and Android Device Monitor. The log message is attached. I can post full log if needed. I've tried on three different AVD's now and the same error occurs on all three.

```
08-04 03:50:48.079: E/BufferQueue(1300): [ScreenshotClient] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceComposer::createGraphicBuffer failed
```

Comment: I've ran into something similar to this before. Though I cannot remember specifically what I did to resolve it, I vaguely remember it being something like File > Invalidate Caches / Restart. No guarantees though.

Comment: @fayerth Where is that? I don't see the option....

Comment: On Windows, it's towards the bottom of the Files menu. I can't vouch it is the same for the OS X version right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to disable host GPU.

I think it's this issue you're experiencing: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60359

Comment: I had a feeling but without Host GPU ticked I can't even get the AVD to start. Left it over an hour and still had black screen.

Answer (score -1):

1. Run your application
2. Click `Android` Icon >> `Screen Capture` Icon from buttom of android studio
3. `Save`

Tutorial: [How to take screenshot from android studio](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/take-screenshot-of-android-app-from-android-studio.html)